# How to hide sign out button on Amplify auth default configuration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

How can I hide the sign out button of amplify default configuration for auth?

I'm using this config to apply Amplify Auth:

```js
export default withAuthenticator(App, true);
```

This button:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot about and took me some time to find this answer, so I'll post it here to help more users:

To the Sign Out default button (generated by the default configuration on `amplify add auth`) you need to pass this props on withAuthenticator HOC:

```js
export default withAuthenticator(App, { includeGreetings: true });
```

To see more about `withAuthenticator` HOC check this super [hidden docs here](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui-legacy/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react)